# Отображение картинок в админке в ManyToMany field

Tags: python, python-3.x, django-admin

```
class ImageItem(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='items/', blank=True)

class Item(models.Model):
    images = models.ManyToManyField(ImageItem)
```

Подскажите, как сделать так чтобы в поле images были видны выбранные картинки?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задача решается в два этапа. Во-первых, необходимо [заменить стандартный виджет для many-to-many на инлайн](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#working-with-many-to-many-models). Во-вторых, надо [добавить в инлайн поле отображающее изображение](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.readonly_fields) в ImageField.

```
class ImagesInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Item.images.through


@admin.register(ImageItem)
class ImageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        ImagesInline,
    ]
    fields = []
    readonly_fields = ['preview']

    def preview(self, obj):
        return '<img src=" + obj.image.url + ">'
    thumbnail.allow_tags = True
    thumbnail.short_description = 'Миниатюра'


@admin.register(Item)
class ItemAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        ImagesInline,
    ]
    exclude = ['images']
```